# Reading Google XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need your help because I'm beginner in PHP and I need to extract information from the Google products feed like below, how I can reach title or link?

I tried to use simplexml_load_file, but with a simple foreach I can't find the right way to isolate the single elements.

Thank you in advance

```
<xml version="1.0">
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
        <channel>
            <title>Title</title>
            <description>Products Brand</description>
            <link>http://www.website.com/</link>
            <item>
                <g:id>1111111</g:id>
                <g:gtin>111111</g:gtin>
                <title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</title>
                <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent in orci efficitur lorem aliquam iaculis non nec orci. Aliquam mattis suscipit nisi in faucibus. Nullam ex mauris, mollis at tellus at, pulvinar mollis orci.</description>
                <g:google_product_category>Apparel &amp; Accessories &gt; Shoes</g:google_product_category>
                <g:product_type>Women &gt; New Arrivals &gt; New Arrivals</g:product_type>
                <link>http://www.brand.com/product.html</link>
                <g:image_link>https://www.brand.com/image_00.png</g:image_link>
                <g:additional_image_link>https://www.brand.com/image_00.png</g:additional_image_link>
                <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            </item>
```

Comment: you need to add your actual code to this question, show what you tried and what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

The XML is slightly wrong, the xml should be `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and I've added any closing tags that are missing.  So the code to display some of the bits is...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("NewFile.xml");

foreach ( $xml->channel as $channel )   {
    foreach ( $channel->item as $item ){
        $title = (string)$item->title;
        $link = (string)$item->link;
        echo $title." => ".$link.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

All it's doing to a foreach for every `<channel>` element and then a foreach for the details of each `<item>` element inside that.

Comment: Hi @Nigel Ren, thank you for your reply. You are right the XML is not complete, I pasted just the first part just for example. I tried your code but I received a page without any output, do you think is possible for the wrong code '<?xml version="1.0"?>'?

Comment: You may have to include the fuller version - sometimes it's due to namespaces etc, but can't tell without the whole document ( You can remove repeated stuff, but need the structure)